# Creating reflexive traits

Tags: rust

```
pub trait Matches<T> {
    fn matches(&self, t : &T) -> bool;
}

impl<S, T> Matches<T> for S where T : Matches<S> {
    
}
```

I am creating a trait `Matches` where a type T may match another type S. I would like to create a reflexive implementation where if I manually implement `Matches<S>` for T, then `Matches<T>` is automatically implemented for S.

This works just fine for most types, but makes it impossible to implement `Matches<T>` for T, as it would have the original `Matches<T>` implementation and a new one generated as a reflection. Is there a way to constraint the types such that T != S, or that S does not implement `Matches<T>` already?

Comment: Not really. Rust doesn't like ambiguous traits. The reasons are fairly complex, but allowing what you're asking for would complicate trait resolution a lot. I'm not even sure you could do this in Scala (where the rules are much looser and the type system can roughly be described as the wild west). By the way, the word you're looking for is "symmetric", not "reflexive".

Comment: That said, why exactly do you need this? Perhaps there's another way to accomplish what you need. Give us a use-case that needs the symmetrical impl.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Ah yes, symmetric was more what I was going for.

Comment: @PitaJ The reason I was going for this symmetric trait was purely for easy usability, such that anything that can match against something else can conversely be matched. Not the end of the world if I can't, but I was curious if Rust had some way of dealing with this sort of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a blanket `impl<S, T> Matches<T> for S where T: Matches<S>`, but you can create a macro to simplify writing the symmetrical `impl`:

```
pub trait Matches<T> {
    fn matches(&self, t: &T) -> bool;
}

macro_rules! impl_symmetrical_matches {
    ($t:ty => $s:ty) => {
        impl Matches<$t> for $s {
            fn matches(&self, other: &$t) -> bool {
                Matches::<$s>::matches(other, self)
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Matches<i32> for u32 {
    fn matches(&self, _t: &i32) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}
impl_symmetrical_matches!(u32 => i32);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8ef5e01191feda2892cd2d8c4e1b06f)

Comment: Why `dyn Matcher`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman because `other.matches` may conflict with an inherent method. I changed it to UFCS which is probably better in this case (although I would expect the compiler to be able to generate the same code for both, but I didn't check).

Comment: Yeah, using UFCS is the alternative I meant to discuss.